# CSS e JS não renderizam em dispositivos moveis

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Meus links rels não abre em dispositivos mobile, como css js e imagens alguém sabe o que pode está acontecendo?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/index.css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/jquery.slides.css"/>
```

Comment: Como assim doido ? Coloca seu código pra nós vermos.

Comment: tipo em no computador ele fica responsivo carrega os estilos e imagens, porem se eu acessar de um dispositivo movel ele quebra os estilos js e imagens

Comment: Coloca aí o código entre as tags `head`.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/index.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/jquery.slides.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/bootstrap.min.css" media="all"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/index.css" media="all"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_CSS_SITE; ?>/jquery.slides.css" media="all"/>
```

Coloque `media="all"` em todos eles como fiz acima. E o que tem nessa variável pré definida `BASE_CSS_SITE` ?

Comment: a url do site sem parametros

Comment: o media não adianta, pois css e imagens tbm nao estao renderizando

Comment: Dá algum erro no Inspect Element ? Seu site está no ar ?

Comment: não local, pois em servidor remoto ele funciona perfeitamente!